# How to display both Find Next and Find Previous buttons in Quick Find in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, productivity-power-tools

By default `-> Find Next` and `<- Find Previous` should be selected from DropDown. Is there any way to display them side by side without need to select from dropDown ?

Or maybe any useful extension for Quick Find exists?

I have installed `Productivity Power Tools` (PPT), it s enabled and working, but doesn't show its own Quick Find dialog instead of default VS2013 dialog. Is any way to prefer PPT over default?

Comment: This is one of the most frustrating things in visual studio.  To save a 20 pixel square of space they force you to to click twice every time you want to move back and forth between search results.  No other program I've ever used has thought it was a good idea to collapse find next/prev into a single dropdown.  I wish I could find a fix.

Comment: Anyone? Six years later an no answers?